# image upload and saving in DB

Tags: php, database, image, upload, save

My main goal is to save every single uploaded image in folder to have uniqe name. i did that but no matter what uniqe name it have, in DB it still have old original name, how can i save same uniqe name in DB ?
My code is:

```
<?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ 
    if(isset($_POST['upload'])) {

$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
$max_size = "100000"; /// 1 Мегабайт
$max_height = "90000"; /// 300 Килобайта
$max_width = "90000"; /// 300 Килобайта
$upload_path = 'gallery/';
$random = md5(time());
$filename = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
$ext = substr($filename, strpos($filename,'.'), strlen($filename)-1);

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_size)
  die('Прекалено е тежка снимката.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_height)
  die('Прекалено е голяма снимка във височина.');

if(filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_width)
  die('Прекалено е голяма снимка във височина.');
if(!is_writable($upload_path))
  die('You cannot upload to the specified directory, please CHMOD it to 777.');

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path .$random . $filename)) {
$q = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET avatar='".$_FILES['userfile']['name']."' WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'");

echo "<font color='#5cb85c'>Браво, успешно си качил/а профилна снимка!</font>"; 


} else {
     echo 'There was an error during the file upload.  Please try again.';
}
}


       echo ' <form action="images.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> ';  
       echo ' <input type="file" name="userfile"/>';
       echo ' <input type="submit" name="upload"  value="Качи">';
       echo ' </form>';


 }
 else
 {
echo "<font color='#ec3f8c'>Съжелявам! За да  качиш снимка във профила си, <a href='login.php'><font color='#ec3f8c'><b> трябва да се логнеш</b> </font></a></font>"; 
 }

    ?>
```

Can someone explain me please, what else i shoud add ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem, the image is saved in the file system with the correct unique name. that is `$upload_path .$random . $filename`, but the reference in the database is wrong.

Simply replace the query

```
UPDATE users SET avatar='".$_FILES['userfile']['name'].
```

with

```
UPDATE users SET avatar='".$upload_path .$random . $filename
```

HTH,
Marcello

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend, it worked 100% :) Perfect code :) :)

Comment: One more question MARCELLO. Everything works fine now. but when i try to upload image who have name on cyrlic in the end it shows up as broken link, what i have to add more in code which will allow me to uoload that kind of images ?

Comment: Probably some cyrillic characters are incompatible with the encoding used by the file system. Is that important for you to keep the original name of the image? If not, you can simply use `$upload_path .$random` instead of `$upload_path .$random . $filename`. If yes, you should do the same and then store the original name in the DB for future uses.

Comment: Thank you a lot Marcello :) but now i have on every weird problem. 
Everything works fine now. i removed @filename. but when i try to "save as" picture it doesnt have in the end .jpeg .png  just nothing ? how can i fix that ? Sorry for too many questions. but i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: that's right, the file extension is part of the filename so, if we remove the filename, we lose the extension :) you can extract the file extension from the filename and then append it to the resulting string, like this: `$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` and use `$upload_path . $random . $filename . '.' . $ext`. If these answers were useful, don't forget to vote them up :)

Comment: Typo: I ment to use `$upload_path . $random . '.' . $ext` (without `$filename`)

Comment: OMG, it is so close now and done almost:
I did this: 
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
My query is: 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$upload_path . $random . '.' . $ext)) {
$q = mysqli_query($connection,"UPDATE users SET avatar='".$random . '.' . $ext."' WHERE username ='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
as results it gives me this as error:
if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))
  die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
Also i have: 
$allowed_filetypes = array('.jpg','.jpeg','.png','.gif');
What shoud i change ?

Comment: well, `pathinfo` gives you the extension without the DOT, while in your list you have DOTjpg, DOTjpeg, etc. Try `array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif')`. Hope this gets the job done!